# Oidc-client in Angular2 with hashlocation giving error in redirect_uri

Tags: angular, identityserver3, oidc-client-js

I am following the [Authenticating Angular2 with Oidc-client](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/SPA-Authentiction-using-OpenID-Connect-Angular-CLI-and-oidc-client) and trying to implement the authentication part. Because the angular2 is using

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```

my urls will change to for eg: http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard.

In the identityserver and also on the client side, i am using redirect_uri as

```
http://localhost:4200/dashboard
```

But after give username and password, the pages redirects to http://localhost:4200/#/id_token and considered as invalid route.

Can anyone help how to solve this when using hashlocationstrategy in angular application and how to configure the identityserver?

Thanks

Comment: give us your full usermanager settings, redirect URI that you are passing in settings.

Answer (score 0):

oidc-client library process signin response by finding the last hash delimiter in your url

https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/c6d76a557626d67e3848b7858cc66787bc77928b/src/SigninResponse.js#L11

So your redirect should typically be configured like this, http://localhost:4200/#/RedirectRouteName#

`${window.location.origin}${window.location.pathname}#/RedirectRouteName#`